# synchronized method read same member variable failed, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

[image]

hi there, anybody can help me?
when multiple threads access `mKeySet`, some one read it as zero size randomly in method `toValue`, not null, why?

```
for (String key : mKeySet) {
    String v = map.get(key);
    if (v == null) {
        v = EMPTY;
    }
    if (i > 0)
        buf.append(",");
    buf.append("'").append(v).append("'");
    i++;
}
```

i just synced the method already?

Comment: map.keySet() returns a Set backed by the map, so when you modify the map outside your method, mKeySet will change too! Instead you have to copy the set e.g. using new HashSet(map.keySet()). Apart from that your method is not synchronized properly, hence not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You've synchronized the method `store` on the class `Datastore`, not the map --- in other words, you're locking the `Datastore` object.

If there's any other users of the map, you need to synchronize on your accesses to `map` --- locking the map itself ---  not the method: `synchronized (map) { // Do things to the map }`